# Why matbugs never stops running?

Tags: matlab, winbugs

I can run a model in WinBUGS14 with no problem and get the results, but I get a problem when I run the same WinBUGS model (shown as below) from MatLab. It looks the program never stops running and no results return.

Can anyone help me. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

1) my WinBUGS Code --- CHK_model.txt

```
model {
for(i in 1: N) {
CF01[i] ~ dnorm(0, 20)
CF02[i]  ~ dnorm(0, 1)
h[i] ~ dpois (lambda [i])
log(lambda [i]) <- beta0 + beta1*CF03[i] + beta2*CF02[i] + beta3*CF01[i] + beta4*IND[i]
}
beta0 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
beta1 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
beta2 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
beta3 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
beta4  <- log(p)
p ~ dunif(lower, upper)
}
```

2) my MatLab Code

```
dataStruct = struct( ... 
    'N', 155, ...
    'lower', 0.80, ...
    'upper', 0.95, ...    
    'h',[1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, ...
         3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, ...
         0, 5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, ...
         1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 5, ...
         0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 3, ...
         3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...
         1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, ...
         0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 6, nan], ...               
    'CF03',[-1.575, 0.170, -1.040, -0.010, -0.750, ...
         0.665, -0.250, 0.145, -0.345, -1.915, -1.515, ...
         0.215, -1.040, -0.035, 0.805, -0.860, -1.775, ...
         1.725, -1.345, 1.055, -1.935, -0.160, -0.075, ...
         -1.305, 1.175, 0.130, -1.025, -0.630, 0.065, ...
         -0.665, 0.415, -0.660, -1.145, 0.165, 0.955, ...
         -0.920, 0.250, -0.365, 0.750, 0.045, -2.760, ...
         -0.520, -0.095, 0.700, 0.155, -0.580, -0.970, ...
         -0.685, -0.640, -0.900, -0.250, -1.355, -1.330, ...
         0.440, -1.505, -1.715, -0.330, 1.375, -1.135, ...
         -1.285, 0.605, 0.360, 0.705, 1.380, -2.385, -1.875, ...
         -0.390, 0.770, 1.605, -0.430, -1.120, 1.575, 0.440, ...
         -1.320, -0.540, -1.490, -1.815, -2.395, 0.305, ...
         0.735, -0.790, -1.070, -1.085, -0.540, -0.935, ...
         -0.790, 1.400, 0.310, -1.150, -0.725, -0.150, ...
         -0.640, 2.040, -1.180, -0.235, -0.070, -0.500, ...
         -0.750, -1.450, -0.235, -1.635, -0.460, -1.855, ...
         -0.925, 0.075, 2.900, -0.820, -0.170, -0.355, ...
         -0.170, 0.595, 0.655, 0.070, 0.330, 0.395, 1.165, ...
         0.750, -0.275, -0.700, 0.880, -0.970, 1.155, 0.600, ...
         -0.075, -1.120, 1.480, -1.255, 0.255, 0.725, ...
         -1.230, -0.760, -0.380, -0.015, -1.005, -1.605, ...
         0.435, -0.695, -1.995, 0.315, -0.385, -0.175, ...
         -0.470, -1.215, 0.780, -1.860, -0.035, -2.700, ...
         -1.055, 1.210, 0.600, -0.710, 0.425, 0.155, -0.525, ...
         -0.565], ...
    'CF02',[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.38, 0.06, -0.94, ...
         -0.02, -0.28, -0.78, -0.95, 2.33, 1.43, 1.24, 1.26, ...
         -0.75, -1.5, -2.09, 1.01, -0.05, 2.48, 2.48, 0.46, ...
         0.46, -0.2, -1.11, 0.52, -0.37, 0.58, 0.86, 0.59, ...
         -0.12, -1.33, 1.4, -1.84, -1.4, -0.76, -0.23, ...
         -1.78, -1.43, 1.2, 0.32, 1.87, 0.43, -1.71, -0.54, ...
         -1.25, -1.01, -1.98, 0.52, -1.07, -0.44, -0.24, ...
         -1.31, -2.14, -0.43, 2.47, -0.09, -1.32, -0.3, ...
         -0.99, 1.1, 0.41, 1.01, -0.19, 0.45, -0.07, -1.41, ...
         0.87, 0.68, 1.61, 0.36, -1.06, -0.44, -0.16, 0.72, ...
         -0.69, -0.94, 0.11, 1.25, 0.33, -0.05, 0.87, -0.37, ...
         -0.2, -2.22, 0.26, -0.53, -1.59, 0.04, 0.16, -2.66, ...
         -0.21, -0.92, 0.25, -1.36, -1.62, 0.61, -0.2, 0, ...
         1.14, 0.27, -0.64, 2.29, -0.56, -0.59, 0.44, -0.05, ...
         0.56, 0.71, 0.32, -0.38, 0.01, -1.62, 1.74, 0.27, 0.97, ...
         1.22, -0.21, -0.05, 1.15, 1.49, -0.15, 0.05, -0.87, ...
         -0.3, -0.08, 0.5, 0.84, -1.67, 0.69, 0.47, 0.44, ...
         -1.35, -0.24, -1.5, -1.32, -0.08, 0.76, -0.57, ...
         -0.84, -1.11, 1.94, -0.68], ...               
    'CF01',[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ...
         nan, -0.117, -0.211, -0.333, -0.229, -0.272, ...
         -0.243, -0.148, 0.191, -0.263, -0.239, -0.168, ...
         -0.381, -0.512, -0.338, -0.296, 0.067, 0.104, ...
         -0.254, -0.167, -0.526, -0.096, -0.43, 0.013, ...
         -0.438, -0.297, -0.131, -0.098, -0.046, -0.063, ...
         -0.194, -0.155, -0.645, -0.603, -0.374, -0.214, ...
         -0.165, -0.509, -0.171, -0.442, -0.468, -0.289, ...
         -0.427, -0.519, -0.454, 0.046, -0.275, -0.401, ...
         -0.542, -0.488, -0.52, -0.018, -0.551, -0.444, ...
         -0.254, -0.286, 0.048, -0.03, -0.015, -0.219, ...
         -0.029, 0.059, 0.007, 0.157, 0.141, -0.035, 0.136, ...
         0.526, 0.113, 0.22, -0.022, -0.173, 0.021, -0.027, ...
         0.261, 0.082, -0.266, -0.284, -0.097, 0.097, -0.06, ...
         0.397, 0.315, 0.302, -0.026, 0.268, -0.111, 0.084, ...
         0.14, -0.073, 0.287, 0.061, 0.035, -0.022, -0.091, ...
         -0.22, -0.021, -0.17, -0.184, 0.121, -0.192, ...
         -0.24, -0.283, -0.003, -0.45, -0.138, -0.143, ...
         0.017, -0.245, 0.003, 0.108, 0.015, -0.219, 0.09, ...
         -0.22, -0.004, -0.178, 0.396, 0.204, 0.342, 0.079, ...
         -0.034, -0.122, -0.24, -0.125, 0.382, 0.072, 0.294, ...
         0.577, 0.4, 0.213, 0.359, 0.074, 0.388, 0.253, 0.167], ...         
    'IND',[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

Nchains = 3;
clear initStructs;

for i=1:Nchains
    S.beta0 = 0;
    S.beta1 = 0;
    S.beta2 = 0;
    S.beta3 = 0;
    S.P     = 0.9;  
    initStructs(i) = S;
end

bugsFolder = 'C:\Program Files\winbugs14\WinBUGS14';
[samples, stats] = matbugs(dataStruct, ...
        fullfile(pwd, 'CHK_model.txt'), ...
        'init', initStructs, ...
        'view', 0, 'nburnin', 1000, 'nsamples', 5000, ...
        'thin', 10, ...
        'monitorParams', {'theta', 'mu_theta', 'sigma_theta'}, ...
        'Bugdir', bugsFolder);
```

Comment: I assume the problem is in the 'matbugs' function code that you don't appear to have posted?

Have you debugged and stepped into/through?

Answer (score 0):

@ N t, thank you so much for your help. I don't know why I cannot response to you by using 'Post your answer". So I response here:

I download the matbugs.m from a website (http://code.google.com/p/matbugs/) and didn't touch this program at all.

When I run the Matlab code (as shown in my post), the computation goes to WinBUGS interface and stops there. Three WinBUGS windows pop up: the first one is WinBUGS Licence window, the second one is Log window, and the third one is Trap window.

1) here is the Log Window; .... data loaded compile(3) model compiled inits(1,

2) here is the Trap Wind ... (pc=764962F9H, fp=0028FB3CH) (pc=76496D39H, fp=0028FBB4H) (pc=764977C3H, fp=0028FC14H) (pc=76497BC9H, fp=0028FC24H) HostMenus.Loop [00003BDEH] .done BOOLEAN FALSE .f SET {0..5} .n INTEGER 0 .res INTEGER 0 .w HostWindows.Window NIL Kernel.Start [00002B8CH] .code PROCEDURE HostMenus.Loop

3) The program of matbugs.m is too long to post here, but I used exactly same program as this one http://code.google.com/p/matbugs/source/browse/trunk/matbugs.m

Thanks again for your time and for your advice!

Bo

Comment: Well, part of the problem is that you didn't follow your account from Stats over to here, so now your two accounts are not associated.